# Using acts_as_state_machine transition methods without saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-state-machine

I want to be able to utilize the acts_as_state_machine transition methods which are auto-generated (e.g. event!).. but I don't want it to save right away. I'm updating the state as part of another set of operations, and so I don't want to be doing double saves.

Is there any way to trigger these event methods without a save right afterward?

Answer (score 5):

By looking at [`acts_as_state_machine`'s code](http://github.com/rubyist/aasm/blob/baceb4b53e296cd45ac3acbd5df291e14b2993aa/lib/aasm.rb) (line 65) I found that it is defining event-methods without a bang too. This will update the state internally in the object without storing it to the database. Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Note the [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem non-bang methods still save the model (they just don't throw exceptions)